# I got an error on insert the object into a linked list array

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, linked-list, jtable

int i=0;

LinkList ls = new LinkList();

int total=0;

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
    Hidden.setText(" ");
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
    try{
    total=0;
    total = total + Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText().toString()) 
            + Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText()) 
            + Integer.parseInt(jTextField3.getText()) 
            + Integer.parseInt(jTextField4.getText())
            + Integer.parseInt(jTextField5.getText())
            + Integer.parseInt(jTextField6.getText())
            + Integer.parseInt(jTextField7.getText())
            + Integer.parseInt(jTextField8.getText())
            + Integer.parseInt(jTextField9.getText())
            + Integer.parseInt(jTextField10.getText())
            + Integer.parseInt(jTextField11.getText())
            + Integer.parseInt(jTextField12.getText());  
    if(!Jname.getText().trim().equals(""))
    {
        if(Jsection.getText().trim().equals("College") || Jsection.getText().trim().equals("Academic Block"))
        {    
            if(total != 0)
            {   
                CleanerInfo cf[] = new CleanerInfo[jTable1.getRowCount()];
                model.addRow(new Object[]{Jname.getText(),Jsection.getText(),total,Jpaymenthr.getText()});
                cf[i] = new CleanerInfo(Jname.getText(),Jsection.getText(),total,Double.parseDouble(Jpaymenthr.getText()));
                ls.insertFront(cf[i]);   
            }
            else
            {
                 Hidden.setText("Please fill in all the months");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Hidden.setText("There are only two section");
        }
    }
    else
    {
    Hidden.setText("Janitor's name can't be empty");
    } 
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e)
    {
        Hidden.setText("Please fill in with numbers");
    }
}
```

Error Occurred : ArrayIndexOutofBound 0 Exception

It supposed to be able to add into the array.

Can anyone proposed a better way to insert the data into the array?

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

Comment: Its because you assigned `i = 0`, and created an array with 0 space to add elements `new CleanerInfo[i]`, change the value of `[i]` and that will do, like this `new CleanerInfo[i + 1]`

Comment: I did that but then I get arrayindexoutofbound 1 exception @Altaris

Comment: `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1` means that the maximum amount of values in your array is 1, and you try to insert a value at an index that does not exist, here your array have capacity of `jTable1.getRowCount()` and you try to insert to the position 'i' that you instantiated with 0 and I can't see where you increment it